# php7.0.33 session_write_close failed

Tags: php, session

I am running the following code and get a $result of false, but how do I see the reason?

```
    session_register_shutdown();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $result=session_write_close();
    if ( !$result ) {
        echo "<LI>session_write_close failed";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: You are using php version 7.0.33? The return type of `session_write_close()` of `bool` has been added in version 7.2.0.

Comment: You are using a version of PHP that has been end of life for more than 2 years now. As @Progman says, `session_write_close()` returns `void` in this old version. Upgrade!